# $\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{x}^{x+h} \ln(t) dt$

Tags: calculus

$\lim_{h \to 0} \int_{x}^{x+h} \ln(t) dt$

Unless I'm missing something, isn't this just $0$ due to how the integral is just $\int_{x}^{x}=0$

I'm sure I could integrate the inside and then evaluate that as $h \to 0$, but this answer seems to deceptively easy if correct

Comment: Are you missing a factor of $1/h$, possibly?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. In words, it's "the limit has h approaches 0 of the integral from x to x+h of ln(t) dt" and that's what I have up there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're correct.  You can argue it that way, or even if you go as far as integrating first you'll find the same result:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{h\to 0} \int_x^{x+h}\ln(t)dt & = & \lim_{h\to 0} \left . t\ln(t) - t \right |_x^{x+h} \\
& = & \lim_{h\to 0}(x+h)\ln(x+h) - (x+h) - x\ln(x) + x \\
& = & \lim_{h\to 0} x \ln\left (\frac{x+h}{x}\right ) + h\ln(x+h) - h \\
& = & x \ln(1) + 0 - 0 \;\; =\;\; 0.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 2):

It is not that trivial for $x=0$, it is an improper integral:
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{0}^{h}\log tdt\right|&=-\int_{0}^{h}\log tdt\\
&=\int_{0}^{h}-\log tdt\\
&=\int_{0}^{h}\log(1/t)dt\\
&\leq C\int_{0}^{h}\dfrac{1}{t^{1/2}}dt\\
&=2C\sqrt{h}\\
&\rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
here $h>0$ is small.

Comment: Hmm, yes, if $x=0$, there would be a technicality.

Where did you get $C$ from?

Comment: $\log x\leq C_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}$ for $x\geq 1$, some suitable constant $C_{\alpha}$, $\alpha>0$, this follows by Mean Value.